# Amazon Web Service RDS Connection Failure

Tags: mysql, apache, amazon-web-services, networking, tcp

I am trying to locally run a PHP based project, connecting to an Amazon RDS instance. I am receiving the following error in the browser:

[![SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykHwv.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykHwv.jpg)

I have run a series of networking tests where I pinged the following and received successful test results. I pinged:

- iiNet's web address
- One of iiNet's DNS servers
- The loopback address of my computer
- I pinged Google

I then tried the mysql utility to remotely connect and received the

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server
```

[image]

Last factor I think you should know regarding my own networking situation, I am connecting to the internet via:

```
modem->Zyxel VPN->Wireless Router->My laptop
```

What in the Sam Hill is going on?
Thanks,
CM

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots of text.

Comment: @DanFarrell right on.

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and include the full error message you get.  From your now deleted comment, I believe you were getting a connection timeout on the mysql port too right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  And I deleted the comment to replace it with the IP address needed to test it or look up/determine whether it was public or private.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, the following must be true:

- the RDS instance must resolve to a *public* IP address (I'd check this for you but since you chose to use a screenshot instead of text, I can't copy paste it, so I'll leave it to you)
- the Security Group(s) associated with the RDS instance must allow traffic from your public IP ( the one you'll get from http://wtfismyip.com/text ).  This *won't* bet true by default.  I highly recommend you open to *your* IP, not just everyone, as Mysql is trivial to DOS attack if its port is public.
- The network ACL of the VPC hosting the RDS instance must allow the traffic also.  This will be allowed by default, so unless you changed the ACLs in your VPC, you can ignore this.

If all those are true, you should be able to connect!

Comment: Here is the RDS instance IP address : 18.237.44.197

casaamazondb.clpn3dsejoqv.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com

Comment: I pinged 18.237.44.197, and the request timed out.

Comment: Great, that's a public address.   A request timeout from mysql indicates the security group is probably closed - disallowed traffic is not refused, it is simply dropped, resulting in an eventual timeout.  Check the security group for your laptop's public IP.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last response. You say the security group (on the server I'm trying to connect to?) is probably closed.  Then you say 'disallowed traffic, is not refused' I don't understand what that means?  Then you say to check the security groups for my laptop's public IP.  Do you mean the security groups within the server I'm trying to connect to? Thanks I appreciate you taking the time to help me understand this.

Comment: Yes, your RDS instance has a security group associated with it.  You'll be able to find it in the console.  It will need to allow your public IP so that you can connect from it.  A security group is essentially a firewall, and it denies by default.  If there is no matching rule allowing your connection, the connection will be silently dropped - which is to say that you won't get a response, so you won't get "connection refused".  Your connection, if not allowed by a security group, will therefore time out because it won't be refused or allowed, just dropped.  Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Yes it makes sense.  This is a project I received from a client.  Seems as if I have to inform the client that they need to go into their AWS console and make these changes.  I will let them know.  When that is done, I will continue trying to connect.  If I do, I will accept your answer as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Ping is going to timeout, because it is blocked by default on AWS. It isn't a good test of connectivity when AWS security groups generally are only open on specific ports for specific protocols.

Comment: True, @MarkB and even if ICMP Ping were allowed at the security group, I don't think RDS instances ever actually respond to a ping.  It will however look up the IP address successfully ( there are other ways but I didn't want to give the OP bad suggestion and don't have windows to test on ).

Comment: @DanFarrell, I supplied my client with my public IP, and I believe he made the change to the security group by adding it.  I tried to connect again and it is still timing out.  I'm not 100% sure the client added my IP, but my client did ask me to give the connection another shot after I supplied.  So I think he did.  Let's assume he did.  And the problem still persists.  Could it be the VPN in my network that is preventing the connection?

Comment: There's too many variables for me to diagnose on SO.  You might have given the wrong IP, it might not have been added, or without the correct port, the VPN may or may not be involved ... You should have the owner give you read-only permissions to his AWS account and you can diagnose this stuff yourself.  Alas, I doubt they'll be able to, if they can't tell you how to reach the database they've provided.